# Creating project in vue taking time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I typed vue create "project name" and it is installing packages for some long time.

there is no error messages it just keeps on installing packages[image]

Answer (score 5):

When I `vue create "proj name here"` I says I need to change npm registry the one in China because my current is slow, It took me 2 hrs patiently waiting for nothing. This was not the same last year when I created new project. I found this tutorial helpful fixing slow creating a new vue https://ozorku.hashnode.dev/how-to-fix-vue-cli-slow-project-creation-cjzqkpx59001ivps1rw4wnhsa. In less than 5 mins or so I download it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered significant speed issues with vue-cli it definitely slows down your computer. Try closing everything except your terminal and see if that helps. The next step would be to free up memory by killing unneeded processes.

Comment: i waited for around 2 hours and it was still installing and i tried using the gui for creating new project it has the same issue .ok i will try it your solution

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Check the vue configuration run vue config

Step 2:
Update the configuration file named '.vuerc' in the resolved path by running the command sudo nano  and change useTaobaoRegistry to false

Step 3:
Save the configuration by pressing CTRL+X and then Y